# Generic JSON to interface

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a JSON like this: (edited json misspelling)

```
{"1":{"id":1,"name":"Name1"}},
{"262":{"id":262,"name":"Name262"}},
```

and goes on...

I'm doing a GET request where I can get the whole thing, like this:

```
getMetaDataObj(): Observable<MetaDataObj> {
  return this.http.get<MetaDataObj>(url).pipe(
    map((res) => {
      return res;
    })
  );
}
```

but I'm not being able to type it.

I'm trying this:

```
export interface Obj{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface MetaDataObj {
  [key: string]: Obj;
}
```

--EDITED to show the subscribe method

I am subscribing to this method like this:

```
getMetaDataObj(){
  this.appService.getMetaDataObj().subscribe((res: MetaDataObj) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

The console.log() prints the whole metaData object, but I want to get only the object

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors from Typescript?

Comment: no.. when I subscribe I am unable to do res.Obj for example.. but I can print the whole json

Comment: Please provide the method where you access `res`. I‘d like to see how exactly you try to get the nested objects.

Comment: @DiabolicWords edited

Answer (score 1):

According to the structure of your JSON, you‘re supposed to get access to the nested content by doing this:

```
// get the nested objects by their string id
var obj1=res['1'];
var obj2=res['262'];


// get the object‘s content
console.log('obj1: ', obj1.name);
console.log('obj2: ', obj2.name);
```

Comment: or if Keys are unknown you can do Object.values(res)

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution, if it helped you.

Comment: That did work.. but I had to do something way too ugly.. A while loop in 4000 objects to push then into the array :(